# Why don't we delete a node in adjacency list after visiting an edge in Fleury algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I was reading an article on fleury's algorithm [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fleurys-algorithm-for-printing-eulerian-path/). In fleury's algorithm, Once an edge is processed (included in Euler tour), we remove it from the graph. To remove the edge, we replace the vertex entry with -1 in adjacency list. 
Note that simply deleting the node may not work as the code is recursive and a parent call may be in middle of adjacency list.

I didn't understand why we can't delete that node, the recursive calls are already built inside the implicit stack. Why will it hinder that?

Comment: What makes you think you can't just delete it?  Why do you think you have to replace it with -1?  What sources are you looking at for Fleury's algorithm?  Have you checked multiple sources?

Comment: @D.W. I have updated my question with relevant information..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Replace the entry with -1" is not part of Fleury's algorithm; that's part of *one implementation* of Fleury's algorithm, and it's just a way to remove the edge.  You'll see that the English description of the algorithm at the web page you linked talks about removing an edge, not setting it to -1.  If you don't like that description, pick another source, and you'll likely find that the other source talks about removing edges, too, not about setting entries to -1.

Comment: Then, is there any significance of this line -"Note that simply deleting the node may not work as the code is recursive and a parent call may be in middle of adjacency list." ?

Comment: @shiwang, sure, yes.  But that's a matter of the implementation, rather than the algorithm.  In C++ iterating through a list while it is being modified can cause unexpected behavior.  That's an implementation concern related to how you implement deleting an edge, not a matter of the algorithm.